# Creating a query to pull very specific information using four tables

Tags: mysql, php

I have four tables, with a structure like this:

**testData**

This table holds all test data for every user.  Each row associates one response for a question, divided up by test.  A user can have many tests, a test can have many unique questions, a question can only have one response.

```
testUUID                               questionUUID                           answerUUID
===================================================================================================================
0d09eea5-4015-4777-92db-44cf48c9b3d6   fd7485fd-5c99-4d26-bdbd-a559b9e47d14   00044311-b9fe-411f-b125-61a40c090068
...(~2 million rows)
```

**answerData**

This table stores the actual answers to the questions.  There is a similarly structured questionData table, but I can work that in later.

```
uuid                                   answerText              answerCorrect
============================================================================
00044311-b9fe-411f-b125-61a40c090068   this is an answer       1
00044234-c820-432a-2003-239ffbbac982   this is another answer  0
```

**testHistory**

This stores data about each test a user has taken.

```
uuid                                   userUUID    (and lots of other columns including score)
==============================================================================================
0d09eea5-4015-4777-92db-44cf48c9b3d6   01b7f715-4142-4436-b527-26b5158578f7
```

**userData**

This stores data about the user.

```
uuid                                   userFirstName (etc.)
===========================================================
01b7f715-4142-4436-b527-26b5158578f7   tehbing
```

I need to figure out.... across all tests that a user has taken, find the questions that are missed the most so they can study those particular questions more often.  Ideally, questionUUID should be in one column and a count for the amount of times a question was missed in another column.  I can do this in PHP, but I feel that this is something the database can do much faster if structured correctly.

**Indexes for the two biggest tables**

```
testData table
Keyname         Type    Unique  Packed  Column          Cardinality Collation   Null
testQuestion    BTREE   Yes     No      testUUID        39354       A           No  
                                        questionUUID    1692249     A           No
testUUID        BTREE   No      No      testUUID        34535       A           No  
questionUUID    BTREE   No      No      questionUUID    11281       A           No  
answerUUID      BTREE   No      No      answerUUID      54588       A           No


testHistory table
Keyname         Type    Unique  Packed  Column          Cardinality Collation   Null
PRIMARY         BTREE   Yes     No  uuid                44965       A           No  
userUUID        BTREE   No      No  userUUID            5620        A           No  
                                    totalQuestions      5620        A           No
                                    questionsMissed     44965       A           No
                                    testScore           44965       A           No
                                    testTimeStarted     44965       A           No
                                    testTimeCompleted   44965       A           No
testArchived    BTREE   No      No  testArchived        4           A           Yes
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3e7b

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY user_id;`

Comment: Thank you. I may have been making this more complicated than it should have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint Rick James provided, I came up with the following.  I'm not sure about efficiency, but it gives me the results I was looking for.

```
SELECT
    testData.questionUUID,
    COUNT(testData.answerUUID) AS wrongAnswerCount
FROM testData
    LEFT JOIN answerData ON answerData.uuid=testData.answerUUID
    LEFT JOIN testHistory ON testHistory.uuid=testData.testUUID
WHERE testHistory.userUUID = ?
    AND answerData.answerCorrect=0
GROUP BY testData.questionUUID
HAVING COUNT(testData.answerUUID) > 5
ORDER BY wrongAnswerCount DESC
```